# How Can I Modify the Default UnitTest1.cs File Template in the Visual Studio 2010 C# Test Project Template?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, projects-and-solutions

I know I can export my own project template, but I'd like to know how to edit the actual, Visual Studio Test Project template's C# UnitTest1.cs file.  I've been unable to locate it in my C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE folder tree.  Anybody know where this lives so I can modify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\BasicUnitTest.zip

Or

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\SimpleUnitTest.zip

1. Extract the files from Archive,
2. Change the SimpleUnitTest.cs as you want
3. Back up the old SimpleUnitTest.zip
4. Zip back the now changed files and name the Archive SimpleUnitTest.zip and copy it to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\1033\ location.

After that:

1. Back up the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\1033\SimpleUnitTest.zip folder
2. copy the changed, unnpacked items (in your case SimpleUnitTest.cs) over to the C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplatesCache\CSharp\1033\SimpleUnitTest.zip.

Comment: Please note that this is not a supported mechanism for making changes - so please do this at your own risk. But having said that, it should work just fine, so have fun with it! :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  I looked all through the file structure but somehow missed "1033" as the obvious foldername for this.

Comment: You don't have to copy over top the cache folder, exist VS2010 and in the Visual Studio Command Prompt run "devenv /installvstemplates".  This takes a few minutes but refreshes the cache.